# What exactly does .selectAll() do?

Tags: d3.js, html-table

I've been playing around with the example ["Using D3.js to present XML as HTML Table"](https://gist.github.com/ashleybot/1873934), to try and learn the **D3.js** API. I think I am getting the hang of it, but I can't really understand what the `.selectAll()` does, and [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-selectAll) on it is not very helpful.

If you look at the example, line 17: `var td = tr.selectAll("td")`. I can also write this as `tr.selectAll("tr")` and it will return the exact same table/page. In fact I can write `tr.selectAll("SomethingCompletelyRandom")` and it will still work, but I can't remove the `.selectAll()`.

What is going on here? What does `.selectAll()` do? And how does it depend on the selector?

Comment: d3 "selections" references: (1) http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/, (2) http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2013/03/05/d3-tutorial-at-strata-redux/, (3) http://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements, (4) http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the API link you point to is using selectAll on a previous selection (it is a sub-selection) so it may not make sense for you to look at (and might be confusing.)  The relevant part of the documentation to look at would be [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_selectAll), and more generally, the introduction to that selection documentation page, [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).

The reason using both `td` and `tr` will work here is that the initial selection returns nothing in both of these cases (since the place you are selecting from, `tr`, has had nothing appended to it yet.)  It is standard practice to select what you will be creating, because when extending this to animations and updating it becomes extremely important.

I would recommend looking at the [Three Little Circles](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) and [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) tutorials

Answer (score 3):

It selects all the `<td>` nodes that are the children of the parent `<tr>` node.  D3 returns this as an array object i.e. `selectAll()` will return an array containing an array of `<td>` nodes as objects and you can call other d3 function on each object.  Also, a good way to understand what's going on behind the scene is to use Chrome developer tools and execute some code in the console.

Example, say you have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you run `d3.selectAll("td")` in the console, the result you get will be:

```
[Array[3]]  // A two dimensional array that contains 3 of the "td" nodes, each of of which is an object.
  >0: td       // A D3 selection object.
  >1: td
  >2: td
   length: 3
   parentNode: document
   __proto__: Array[0]
```