# Can selectAll() in d3 js take css style also as parameter?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am new to javascript and d3. While working on few examples I came across some lines like this :  `var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")`

I saw this while creating a legend for my scatterplot. This was part of the accepted solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452742/add-a-static-definite-legend-in-d3js-graph)

1. Why are we giving .legend as a parameter?
2. Is .legend a CSS style?
3. In general what all can we pass as argument to selectAll()?

I have worked out these set of examples ([Scott Murray's tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials)) but I am still confused on how selectAll works. Any guidance/explanation/links to read is really appreciated.

Comment: Usually the best place to answer a question like "what can I do with method X" is the documentation: [`d3.selectAll`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selectAll). There's also [What exactly does .selectAll() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15259667/215552)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d3.selectAll(selector)](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selectAll)

> Selects all elements that match the specified selector string. The elements will be selected in document order (top-to-bottom). If no elements in the document match the selector, or if the selector is null or undefined, returns an empty selection. For example, to select all paragraphs:
>
> var paragraph = d3.selectAll("p");

**1)** In your example, `.legend` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). It is being passed as an argument to `selectAll` to match all DOM elements that have a class of `legend`.

**2)** `.legend` is not a CSS style itself. But it *can* be used in CSS as a selector to apply some style properties to the elements that match said selector.

**3)** `selectAll` accepts only one argument: a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) string. That could simply be `"p"` or it could be `".content .items > li"`.

---

Have a look below how we can use both CSS & D3 to apply different styles.

```js
d3.selectAll(".highlight")
  .style({
    "color": "green"
  })
```

```css
nav a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare" class="highlight">Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor" class="highlight">Pellentesque</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```